# How to embed a tree structure within a column of a table

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to build a UI that displays items in a list, with additional details displayed in other columns in the list.  When an item contains child items, I can expand the item and additional rows will be inserted into the table, and the names of the items will be indented, but the rest of the columns display normally.

The challenge is that normally a tree structure is done recursively.  But you can't have a node serve as the parent of the child rows, or it breaks the table.

I was able to get a proof of concept, like so:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Summary</th>
    <th>Priority</th>
  </thead>
  <ng-template ngFor let-root [ngForOf]="['a','b','c']">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left: 0;">{{root}}</td>
      <td>Summary for {{root}}</td>
      <td>None</td>
    </tr>
    <ng-template ngFor let-child [ngForOf]="['1','2','3']">
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-left: 1em;">{{child}}</td>
        <td>Summary for {{child}}</td>
        <td>None</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-template>
</table>
```

This works because the `<ng-template>` does not render as a node in the DOM.

Next I tried to create a component to represent this concept:

```
<tr>
  <td style="padding-left: calc({{depth}}*1em);">
    {{item.nodeName()}}
  </td>
  <td *ngIf="details">{{item.summary}}</td>
  <td *ngIf="details">{{item.priority_name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr *ngIf="loading">
  <td *ngIf="details" style="padding-left: calc({{depth+1}}*1em);" colspan=3>Loading...</td>
  <td *ngIf="! details" style="padding-left: calc({{depth+1}}*1em);">Loading...</td>
</tr>
<ng-template ngFor let-child [ngForOf]="item.children">
  <item-node [item]="child" depth="depth+1" [details]="details"></item-node>    
</ng-template>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work because `<item-node>` creates a node in the DOM that breaks the table.

Is there a way to do this in a way that doesn't insert extraneous nodes in the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `<ng-template>` and `<ng-container>`, to create a recursive template, like so:

```
<ng-template #node>
  <tr><!-- current node --></tr>
  <ng-container *ngIf="expanded">
    <ng-container ngFor let-child [ngForOf]="children">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="node; context:child"></ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
<table>
  <thead><!-- column headers --></thead>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="node; context: root"></ng-container>
</table>
```

There are more details that have to be worked out, like how to make the indentation work (you need to keep track of the depth, and add a style that indents based on the depth), you have to pass in the variables to be pulled from the context, etc.  But the root problem, how to avoid having unnecessary elements in the DOM, are solved using `<ng-container>` and the child nodes are handled by using a recursive `<ng-template>` in place of a stand-alone component.

Read up on `<ng-template>` and `<ng-container>` for the details.